# How to access the parameter, that has the Attribute attached?

Tags: .net, vb.net, parameters, attributes

This is my Code:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)>
Public Class attCallerInfo
    Inherits Attribute

    Public Sub New(<CallerFilePath> Optional path As String = logOrigin.path_default,
                   <CallerMemberName> Optional method As String = logOrigin.method_default)

        Me.Origin = New logOrigin(path, method)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Origin As logOrigin

End Class
```

... and the way it's supposed to be called:

```
Public Sub New(<attCallerInfo()> Optional ByRef origin As logOrigin = Nothing)
```

Infos on the code:

- This attribute is attached to multiple loggers, that log stuff I want to know.
- Path and Method make clear to me, where something happend.
- logOrigin is a class, that tranforms the whole path and method-name into something more suitable for my task.

How do I now achive, that my attCallerInfo is called, fetches the file and member and passes them to my parameter origin (2nd code block)?

Thx for the help
Daedra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not solve the problem with another attribute but a normal class, like this: (I call your not further specified class containing the constructor `Foo` in my excample...)

```
Public Class Foo

    Public Sub New(<CallerFilePath> Optional path As String = Nothing, <CallerLineNumber> Optional lineNumber As Int32 = 0, <CallerMemberName> Optional method As String = Nothing)
        Me.New(New CallerInfo(path, lineNumber, method))
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(callerInfo As CallerInfo)
        'Do something with it...
        Me.CallerInfo = callerInfo
    End Sub

End Class
```

and the CallerInfo you implement as normal class:

```
Public Class CallerInfo

    Public Sub New(path As String, lineNumber As Int32, method As String)
        Me.Path = path
        Me.LineNumber = lineNumber
        Me.Method = method
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Path As String
    Public ReadOnly Property LineNumber As Int32
    Public ReadOnly Property Method As String

End Class
```

And the usage of `Foo` is simple like this:

```
Dim myFoo As New Foo()
```

Comment: I kinda solved it like that in the end, but without the last code section. I created a module, that has a Function called FOO(...), that has the parameters of your Foo-Constructor, and that returns me a new Foo-Instance. This way, I can use it everywhere like Method(stuff, moreStuff, FOO). Don't like it 100%, but it works and does the job for me.